# document.getElementById('input').value Returns an empty string

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make a button that when clicked adds an input tag to the page and gives it an id. The  code to get the id is stored in an object. The code looks like this:

```
document.getElementById('signup-students-input' + currentInputTagNumber ).value
```

Then the code is ran through an eval function like so

```
console.log (eval(theObject.getInfo()))
```

And the eval creates this code

```
document.getElementById('input-3').value
```

However, this returns an empty string in the console and using an alert function.

I've attached a code snippet  below:

```js
        var newStudentBtn = document.getElementById ("new-student");
        var students = document.getElementById ("students");
        var signupStudents = 1;
        var cost = document.getElementById ("cost");
        var confiredStudent = "";
        
        let ids = new Object ();
        ids.idNames = "";
        ids.getInfo = function () {
            return this.idNames;
        };


        
        var newStudentBtnOnClick = function () {
            signupStudents++;
            let newStudent = document.createElement ("input");
            newStudent.placeholder="Type your child's first and last name here";
            newStudent.id = "signup-students-input" + signupStudents;
            
            let newStudentHeading = document.createElement ("h3");
            let studentNewLine = document.createElement ("br");
            newStudentHeading.innerHTML = "Child (" + signupStudents + ") First and Last Name";
            students.appendChild (newStudentHeading)
            students.appendChild (newStudent);
            
            cost.innerHTML = signupStudents*39
            if (signupStudents === 2) {
            ids.idNames += "document.getElementById(" + "'signup-students-input' + signupStudents " + ").value "
            }
            else {
                ids.idNames += "+ document.getElementById ('signup-students-input' + signupStudents).value "
            }
            
            
            console.log (ids.getInfo())
            console.log (eval(ids.getInfo()))
        };
        newStudentBtn.addEventListener ("click", newStudentBtnOnClick);
```

```html
    <div class="nav-bar">
        <nav>
            <a href="index.html"><img src="img_2.jpg" class="nav-img"></a>
            <div class="nav-options">
                <button class="nav-option">About Us</button>
                <button class="nav-option">Classes</button>
                <button class="nav-option">Contact Us</button>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </div>
    <div class="welcome">
        <h1>Signup for the Intermedite Class</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="info-content">
        <div class="diveder"><h2>Please fill out the form</h2></div>
       
        <div class="info-content-blocks">
            <form>
                <div id="students">
            <h3>Parent First and Last Name</h3>
            <input placeholder="Type your first and last name here" required id="parent-name">
            <h3>Child (1) First and Last Name</h3>
            <input placeholder="Type your child's first and last name here" required class="student-names" id="student-1-name">
        </div>
            
        <br><br><button class="standard-button" id="new-student" type="button">New Student</button><br><br>
            <h3>Parent Email Address</h3>
            <input placeholder="Type your email address here" required id="email">
            <h3>Parent Phone Number (For Emgerency Contact Only)</h3>
            <input placeholder="Type your phone number here" required id="phone">
            <p>Please pay $<span id="cost">39</span> cash after your childs first class.</p>
            <button class="standard-button" type="submit" id="send-btn">Enroll</button>

</form>
        </div>
        
        
    </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Try to produce a simpler example that shows the problem you have - there's too much to go through to help you at the moment,

Comment: What is the expected output of `eval(ids.getInfo())`?

Comment: @luek baja The expected output is the string entered into the page see the updated code snipit on the question.

Comment: @luek baja  Please view the code preview on codepen: https://codepen.io/Tech-World/pen/RwMeKvB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that you are adding a string to ids.idNames instead of the variable signupStudents. I also changed the id of the default input from "student-1-name" to "signup-students-input1" and changed the ids.idNames default value. Here's a demo:

```js
var newStudentBtn = document.getElementById ("new-student");
        var students = document.getElementById ("students");
        var signupStudents = 1;
        var cost = document.getElementById ("cost");
        var confiredStudent = "";
        
        let ids = new Object ();
        // changed this line
        ids.idNames = "document.getElementById('signup-students-input1').value";
        ids.getInfo = function () {
            return this.idNames;
        };


        
        var newStudentBtnOnClick = function () {
            signupStudents++;
            let newStudent = document.createElement ("input");
            newStudent.placeholder="Type your child's first and last name here";
            newStudent.id = "signup-students-input" + signupStudents;
            
            let newStudentHeading = document.createElement ("h3");
            let studentNewLine = document.createElement ("br");
            newStudentHeading.innerHTML = "Child (" + signupStudents + ") First and Last Name";
            students.appendChild (newStudentHeading)
            students.appendChild (newStudent);
            
            cost.innerHTML = signupStudents*39

            /* changed these lines */
            ids.idNames += "+ document.getElementById('signup-students-input" + signupStudents + "').value";
            
            
            console.log (ids.getInfo())
            console.log (eval(ids.getInfo()))
        };
        newStudentBtn.addEventListener ("click", newStudentBtnOnClick);
```

```html
<div class="nav-bar">
        <nav>
            <a href="index.html"><img src="img_2.jpg" class="nav-img"></a>
            <div class="nav-options">
                <button class="nav-option">About Us</button>
                <button class="nav-option">Classes</button>
                <button class="nav-option">Contact Us</button>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </div>
    <div class="welcome">
        <h1>Signup for the Intermedite Class</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="info-content">
        <div class="diveder"><h2>Please fill out the form</h2></div>
       
        <div class="info-content-blocks">
            <form>
                <div id="students">
            <h3>Parent First and Last Name</h3>
            <input placeholder="Type your first and last name here" required id="parent-name">
            <h3>Child (1) First and Last Name</h3>
            <!-- this line changed -->
            <input placeholder="Type your child's first and last name here" required class="student-names" id="signup-students-input1">
        </div>
            
        <br><br><button class="standard-button" id="new-student" type="button">New Student</button><br><br>
            <h3>Parent Email Address</h3>
            <input placeholder="Type your email address here" required id="email">
            <h3>Parent Phone Number (For Emgerency Contact Only)</h3>
            <input placeholder="Type your phone number here" required id="phone">
            <p>Please pay $<span id="cost">39</span> cash after your childs first class.</p>
            <button class="standard-button" type="submit" id="send-btn">Enroll</button>

</form>
        </div>
        
        
    </div>
    </div>
```